# How to do sql loop

Tags: mysql, sql

Table `works(emNo, comNo, salary)`.

I can get distinct comNo using "select distinct comNo from works`". Suppose it gives me a column with 5 rows. How do I count "`emNo`" for each of those rows?

Comment: Do you like to count or to sum the values?

Comment: Ok, reading your question carefully I understand that you want to count ;)

Comment: but i need to get the max in the count column. how do i get that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` to aggregate per type of `comNo`.

```
SELECT
  comNo,
  count(emNo)
FROM
  works
GROUP BY
  comNo
```

This will return one row per distinct value of `comNo` along with the count of records per group.

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f5df/1

Comment: i also need to get the max in the count column. how do i get that?

Comment: You can sort by `count(emNo)`, and then take the first row, e.g., `.... ORDER BY count(emNo) DESC LIMIT 1`: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f5df/17

Comment: .... ORDER BY count(emNo) DESC

this gives me result but when i add

.... ORDER BY count(emNo) DESC limit 1

i get error (command not properly ended)